# Comparing server-side clock to datatable with a return

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a conditional statement that needs to be executed on the server-side for my datatable. I'm not too familiar with C# and how I should link this external event to my aspx page. Within my datatable I have a column called "Scheduled Time" that needs to be compared to the server-side clock, and return this event below on the datatable row.

I'm using military time, by the way

```
scheduledTime >15mins; return background-color:red; color:white;
scheduledTime >15min<=30mins; return background-color:yellow color:black;
scheduledTime >30mins<=2hours; return background-color:green color:white;
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where is this background color going (table cell, div, etc.)? How is the ASP page connected to your database (ADO.NET?)

Comment: Yes I tried but I am not getting a reponse on the table. I used this example but Im not sure if its reading my datatable correctly YourGridViewName_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
       // Do your color change here by accessing the col with e.Row.Cells[column_index].BackColor = 'what ever you want'
    }
}

Comment: What did you try? I don't see anything that even closely resembles to C# in your question. Could you please go ahead and update your question by providing the code you have tried? Please do not use the comments section to post code samples as it is not very readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TimeSpan to get difference between 2 times:

TimeSpan ts= DateTime.Parse("") - DateTime.Now;

var scheduledTime = ts.Minutes;

Now you are able to compare your sheduledTime.

Answer (score 0):

if you're planning something like to bind a datatable into gridview ;you could sure change cell background in the RowDataBound event.